# Just upgraded from Spring Boot 2.7.4 to Spring Boot 3.0.0, caused error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Upgraded the application from Spring 2.7.4 to 3.0.0
Got the following exception while trying to run

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@eaa1a4da]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417)


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodsImpl(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: It is because this class might have been moved or removed from the `javax.servlet` package, expand your dependencies to find out where this class is, most likely you may have to downgrade it if that class isn't in 3.0.0

Comment: You should go through this doc carefully, it's all pretty well explained: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: You are mixing Spring Security and Spring Boot with incompatible versions. Generally this means your dependencies are mess. Use the `spring-boot-starter-security` and remove any plain `org.springframework.security` dependencies you have or think you need to manage yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [release notes for Spring-Boot 3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes) state that:

> ...
>
> Spring Boot 3.0 has migrated from Java EE to Jakarta EE APIs for all dependencies. Wherever possible, Jakarta EE 10 compatible dependencies have been chosen, including:
>
> ...
>
> - Jakarta Servlet 6.0
>
> ...

As such, the import changed from `javax.servlet` to `jakarta.servlet`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from Spring Boot 2.x.x to 3.x.x, then make sure that you have dependency on

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security`

and remove any dependencies on `org.springframework.boot:spring-security-*`

Answer (score -1):

You should change `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` wherever applicable in your project to migrate to Spring boot 3.0.0